# Allow no default instance to be registered with StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap

We have an interface which is implemented by two classes:

```
public interface ISomething { void DoSomething(); }
public class Something1 : ISomething { public void DoSomething() {...} }
public class Something2 : ISomething { public void DoSomething() {...} }
```

These interfaces are used by two different modules.  `Module1` needs `Something1` and `Module2` needs `Something2`:

```
public class Module1(ISomething something) { something.DoSomething(); }
public class Module2(ISomething something) { something.DoSomething(); }
```

We set this up in a registry:

```
For<Module1>().Use<Module1>().Ctor<ISomething>().Is<Something1>();
For<Module2>().Use<Module2>().Ctor<ISomething>().Is<Something2>();
```

However, when it runs, we get the following error:

> No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'ISomething'

If we create and register a default class, then it works and we do not get the above error:

```
public class DefaultSomething : ISomething { public void DoSomething() {...} }
For<ISomething>().Use<DefaultSomething>();
```

All the uses of the interface are configured in the registry and we do not want to have to specify a default, but it seems like you have to tell StructureMap what to use, even if it never needs to use it.  Is it possible to not have to specify a default instance?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes we do (`WithDefaultConvention` and `SingleImplementationsOfInterface`)

Comment: `Something1` and `Something2` (The first code block in the question)

Comment: Ah, well the way you've written it you're basically saying Module1 uses Module1, oh and I want you to specifically use a constructor with ISomething. It doesn't know what ISomething is

Comment: @sr28 Agreed that having to put `For<Module1>().Use<Module1>()` feels slightly redundant, but that's just the API available. However, from that, `Module1` should know to use an instance of `Something1` when it needs to resolve `ISomething`, as defined by `.Ctor<ISomething>().Is<Something1>();`.